# Cumulative vs. non-cumulative IRFs in R

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am using `irf` function from **vars** package. I am trying to derive cumulative IRFs.

The following code describes the case of deriving cumulative IRFs:

```
irf(vecm.l, impulse = c("g","p","h","l","s"), response = "g",  cumulative = TRUE,n.ahead = 20, ortho=TRUE)
```

I got the output and plotted it, it looked like cumulative values of estimated MA coefficients. But then I ran the code with `cumulative` switched to `FALSE` as below:

```
irf(vecm.l, impulse = c("g","p","h","l","s"), response = "g",  cumulative = FALSE,n.ahead = 20, ortho=TRUE)
```

Output from these two codes is identical. Including `cumulative = TRUE`in the `irf` function does not produce the cumulative responses??

Please note that I converted a `vecm` model to `var` using `vec2var`, hence the input model is called `vecm.l` here. Though, I doubt it plays any significance in deriving cumulative IRFs.

I would appreciate your comment, am I specifying the function incorrectly?
Thanks,